# If I upgrade my Ruby from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2, do I have to reinstall all my gems?

Tags: passenger, ruby-1.9.2

I'm particularly worried about whether I need to upgrade Passenger and recompile my Passenger apache module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When upgrading I had to recompile my passenger apache module.  I had quite a few issues but this post helped: http://www.prestonlee.com/2010/09/24/upgrading-from-ruby-1-9-1-to-ruby-1-9-2/